# How to access any particular data in highchart tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am using highcharts to display a graph.

I am having trouble displaying the time in the tooltip.

If i send time in data object of seriesdata object it displays correctly but not the other way around.

```
var renderchart = function (seriesData) {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'barGrpahcontainer',
            type: 'bar',
            backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
            animation: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            opposite: false,
            categories: null,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            labels: {
                enabled:false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            opposite: true
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.y + '<br/>' + 'Time: ' + this.time;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                pointWidth: 20
            }
        },
        series: seriesData
    });
}

var dataArray = [{"status":"Program Running","y":0.08,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:13:47"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.02,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:03:41"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.04,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:07:36"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.0,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:00:28"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.0,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:00:14"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.04,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:07:45"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.21,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:37:43"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.0,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:00:47"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.13,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:24:00"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.01,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:01:55"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.04,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:07:36"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.0,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:00:19"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.0,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:00:16"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.05,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:08:52"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.21,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:37:46"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.02,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:02:53"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.13,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:24:03"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.02,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:03:24"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.04,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:07:50"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.0,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:00:11"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.0,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:00:09"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":0.0,"color":"#FEC201","time":"00:00:21"},{"status":"Program Running","y":0.0,"color":"#01BC01","time":"00:00:20"},{"status":"Program Stopped","y":1.67,"color":"#FEC201","time":"05:00:27"},{"status":"NO DATA","y":5.26,"color":"#444849","time":"15:47:37"}]


$(function () {
    var data = dataArray;
    var seriesData = [];
    var total = 0;
    var i, cat;
    var count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        seriesData.push({
            name: data[i].status,
            data: [data[i].y],
            color: data[i].color,
            time: data[i].time
        });
    }

    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        renderchart(seriesData)
    });
});
```

Comment: please look at the js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/bvdm652t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of that is parameter, which is kept in `this.series.options.time` instead of `this.time`.

Fixed formatter:

```
 tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
      this.y + '<br/>' +
      'Time: ' + this.series.options.time;
  }
},
```

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/vwdzxawv/

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian ..!!